# How to turn off the azure event-hub of kafka by setting up it due spring in yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I tried this, but it doesn't help

spring:
autoconfigure:
exclude:
- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingsEndpointAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelsEndpointAutoConfiguration
- org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Kafka components are auto-configured by Spring Boot even when you set `spring.kafka.consumer.enabled` and `spring.kafka.producer.enabled` to `false`. To be more explicit, you can exclude the `KafkaAutoConfiguration` class in your main application class.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class YourApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

- You can enable debug logging for Spring Boot to see what auto-configuration is taking place. In your `application.yaml` (or `application.properties`)

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure: DEBUG
```

- If you disabled Kafka in your application configuration and have confirmed that it's not auto-configured, and you don't see Kafka-related settings or Event Hubs in the Azure Portal or Azure CLI

If you are having Azure Spring Cloud Stream Binder in the project.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          binder: kafka
        output:
          binder: kafka
    function:
      definition: myFunction
    azure:
      eventhub:
        enabled: false
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaBinderAutoConfiguration
```

- Exclude `KafkaBinderAutoConfiguration` to prevent Spring Boot from auto-configuring the Kafka binder.

Use this command to check in Azure eventhub namespace - `az eventhubs eventhub list --resource-group <resource-group-name> --namespace-name <namespace-name>`.

[image]